# How to adjust the height of a tableView Cell based on html content of the web-view inside it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have seen the solutions where we find the height of a webview based on content but that happens after the webview has been loaded.

my webview is inside a TableView Cell, Its height depends on what height I give to tableView whose height should depend on content.

I have a maximum limit for height but if the content takes lesser space I would like to reduce it a bit.

Now How do I gracefully do it, as Cell's height is controlled by tableView delegates.
shall I send a delegate message from cell to reload the tableView or cell with new height ?

Comment: Put your content (HTML) in custom controller and set size of cell base on this custom controller :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the webviews and load the contents first, make sure the height of the webview is zero
2. After all the webview was loaded, set the TableView's Delegate and DataSource, modify the height of all the webviews.
3. Override -(CGFloat)height...tableview indexPath.... As below

   {  return eachWebviewInside.scrollview.contentSize.height;}

Comment: at a time there willonly be one webview. the selected cell will expand to show a webview. any other expanded cell collapses and webview in it is released.

Comment: Finally, You should loaded each page's contents first before reload the tableview, then you can get the height of the web page by using javascript(document.body.scrollHeight).  After then reload page to avoid screen flash